# custom django form template (in bootstrap)

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I would like to customize my django forms.
For example, in my code I have working hour settings which I like to produce like this format:

```
mon_start mon_end
tue_start tue_end
....
```

but instead it creates a form

```
mon_start 
mon_end
tue_start 
tue_end
....
```

Here is a view of the output that I dont want
[image]

Below are my code:

forms.py

```
class CompanyWorkingHoursSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mon_start = forms.TimeField()
    mon_end = forms.TimeField()
    tue_start = forms.TimeField()
    tue_end = forms.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Workinghours
        fields = ("mon_start","mon_end","tue_start","tue_end")
```

workinghourssettings.html

```
{% extends 'project/base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block page %}
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading bg-blue">
        <h4 class="panel-title text-center text-white">
          Working Hours Settings
        </h4>
      </div>
        <div class="panel-body">         
          <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}            
            {% bootstrap_form company_workinghourssettings_form %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-pink">Update</button>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

How do i produce a custom arranged form for my form fields above ? (in bootstrap)

Comment: I would suggest you to "unpack" your form and to use the bootstrap libray manually instead of using that django-extension called bootstrap3... Do this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually ... After rendering form fields manually just add bootstrap css's classes!

Comment: First, read how bootstrap uses the [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#responsive-classes). Secondly, you would need to change the HTML in the `company_workinghourssettings_form`

Comment: use crispy form it is much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you may try rendering your fields one by one, and apply bootstrap grid:

```
<form>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">{{ my_form.field_1 }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-6"{{ my_form.field_2 }}></div>

    </div>
    ....


</form>
```

Comment: thanks, it works. but how do i add bootstrap form-control for the fields. can i do it in forms.py fields definition ?

Comment: yes, check the other answer, in widget attrs you can define `mon_start =forms.TimeField(label='the label', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))`

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is with the placeholder you can just use

```
mon_start =forms.TimeField(label='the label', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'What ever you want here'}))
```